# How to gain permissions in OS X for Python app compiled using Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, macos, permissions, pyinstaller

I wrote a script in Python with some IO operation like:

```
inputfileHandle = open(inputfile, 'rb')
outputfileHandle = open(outputfile, 'wb')
# ... some actions performed ... #
outputfileHandle.write(result)
```

And then I try to compile the script using Pyinstaller. When I run the app everything works fine but if I distribute it to other Mac user, it shows "Operation nor permitted". I guess this is because the app doesn't have the permission to write the file. How can I deal with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: The act of "if I distribute it to other Mac user" doesn't preserve file attributes though...